# PHP PDO MySql

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте не очень разбираюсь в PHP(OOP) но не могу понять почему выводит эту ошибку

**Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in**

Вот код но когда делаю этот запрос в классе db то ошибки нету выборка проходит но унаследовая класс не получается объясните пожалуйста что делаю не правильно большое спасибо

```
class db {
    const DB_HOST = "localhost";    
    const DB_NAME = "test";    
    const DB_USER = "root";    
    const DB_PASS = "";

    protected $DB;

    function __construct() {
        $DB = new PDO('mysql:host='.self::DB_HOST.';dbname='.self::DB_NAME.';charset=UTF-8', self::DB_USER, self::DB_PASS);
    }

    function __destruct() {
        unset($DB);
    }
}

class web extends db {

    function viewWeb() {

        $STH = $this->DB->query('SELECT web_id, web_name, web_img FROM web');  
        $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        while($row = $STH->fetch()) {  
            echo $row->web_id . "\n";  
            echo $row->web_name . "\n";  
            echo $row->web_img . "\n";  
        }
    }    
}

$n = new web();
$n->viewWeb();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function __construct() {
    $this->DB = new PDO('mysql:host='.self::DB_HOST.';dbname='.self::DB_NAME.';charset=UTF-8', self::DB_USER, self::DB_PASS);
}

function __destruct() {
    unset($this->DB);
}
```

Не забываем `$this` =)

Comment: большое спасибо сработало

Comment: точно... пора спать :)

Answer (score 0):

Всё правильно.

Что бы избежать ошибки - перейменуйте метод web в что ли бо иное. Иначе оно перекрывает родительский конструктор.

Comment: нет проблема не в этом у меня раньше он по другому назывался и сейчас изменил ишибка в query()

Comment: приведите код, как используйте, как создаете и т.д

Comment: ну там ничего обычного код дополнил можете взглянуть